# how to show suggestions in eclipse IDE for ROKU development

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am currently developing a ROKU channel in eclipse IDE. And when i start typing it's didn't show any suggestion of variables and methods.
  Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For a better experience, I recommend that you switch to Atom with the following packages:

- [roku-deploy](https://atom.io/packages/roku-deploy)
- [language-brightscript](https://atom.io/packages/language-brightscript)

There is also the option to use Roku's own package, but you will have to add it manually. For more information see their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rokudev/atomio-package)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Roku plugins in eclipse IDE.
Please have a look here

#### https://blog.roku.com/developer/roku-eclipse-plugin

#### https://devtools.web.roku.com/ide/eclipse/plugin/